# WPF if sizechanged event does not bubble, does it tunnel?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, layout

I noted that according to:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.sizechanged%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

the sizechanged event does not bubble upwards to parent elements. Does it tunnel downward then? I'm just curious how sizechanged works exactly. After a size on an element changes, does the event propagate in some direction until it is handled? if it doesn't propagate then how is it a routed event.

Comment: Might be unrelated, but you don't usually handle events in WPF. and you absolutely do NOT do layout in WPF using SizeChanged events. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is actually 3rd [routing strategy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx#routing_strategies). Direct events which neither bubble nor tunnel and are raised only by one control and [`FrameworkElement.SizeChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.sizechanged.aspx) is exactly one of these events.

Comment: It should probably also be noted that `SizeChanged` in a parent control can trigger a `SizeChanged` in the child control too, so even if the event itself doesn't bubble downwards, you may have multiple direct `SizeChanged` events firing.

Comment: Technically changing the size of one control can even trigger `SizeChanged` event on every control, if only `ActualWidth` or `ActualHeight` has changed due to layout update.